# how to Copy unique members of structures in C

Tags: c, structure

I was doing homework in programming (C language), and I came up to a problem which I can't solve despite hard effort.

Before I ask about specific problem, I want to show you what is given :

> In the first plain text file (F1) are stored movies titles with all the data. In the second plain text file (F2) – review of movies,
> listed in file F1, by ordinary users and movie critics. Each film can
> be evaluated by an unlimited number of movie critics and ordinary
> users. One and the same person may be a director in several movies.
> Also, every critic/user can participate in the evaluation of several
> movies.
>
> · Display on the screen all the critics (movie critics and ordinary
> users), the number of movies they have rated and an average mark. Sort
> the critics by the number of marks (from greatest to lowest).

So my structure of reviews looks like this :

```
struct Review{
char ID[20];
char MovieID[20];
char FamilyName[20];
char Critic;
double Mark;


};
```

I have created array of structure with dynamic memory allocation. What I need is to identify each unique author of review by FamilyName, calculate the number of movies they have rated (so number of times their FamilyName occurs in Reviews) and average Mark they have given to all movies.

By far, I was thinking about creating new structure of User, which will have all those 3 members Familyname, Number of movies rated, AverageMark. But I can not think of algorithm to copy only unique values from Review[] to User[]...
After I have done it sorting will not be a problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The task is mostly about database design. An example struct layout to use follows:

```
struct Movie {
  int ID;
  char MovieName[20];
  int DirectorId; /* lookup in Person */
};

struct Person {
  int Id;
  char Surname[20];
  char Firstname[20];
  /* numbers of reviews, movies directed etc, can be calculated, and should not be stored to disk */
  int NumberOfReviews;
  int SumMarks; /* AverageMark = SumMarks / NumberOfReviews */
};

struct Review {
  int Id;
  int MovieId;
  int AuthorId; /* Lookup in person */
  int Mark;
};
```

Next you need to make an array or linked list of these, make routines to load data from disk and printing out the reports.

Comment: Yes i have structures like these, but the thing is that Review and Movie is read and stored from txt file and what I really need to do is to fill in Person structure using Review, which seems quite difficult for me.  I am seeking for general algorithm of how to copy and process data from one array to another without duplicated content or From Review to Person without duplicated authors. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You read one and one line from the txt files. If the files contains a Name for a person on each record, you first check if that person already exists in memory, if so, reuse the same id, else add the person and use the new uniqe id.